# How do I declare a member template class an friend of the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, nested

I have some class

```
template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
  class TestBuilder
  {
    template<typename Int>
      class Helper
      {};
  };
```

How do I make `Helper` a `friend` of `TestBuilder`?
I tried:

```
template<typename Int>
  friend class Helper;
```

but that just makes friends of namespace scope `Helper` classes friends of `TestBuilder`

Comment: Helper is nested within TestBuilder, it already has a full access to any private member of any TestBuilder object.

Answer (score 3):

But `Helper` is a **nested class** of TestBuilder, isn't it? :)

As a result, it has access to the members of the outer class (yes, and its private members), check the example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
class TestBuilder
{
  int n;
  char c;

public:
  template<typename Int>
  class Helper
  {
  public:
    void print(TestBuilder& tb) {
      std::cout << tb.n << " " << tb.c << std::endl;
    }
  };
  TestBuilder(int n, char c) : n(n), c(c) {}

};

int main() {
        TestBuilder<int, int> tb(5, 'p');
        TestBuilder<int, int>::Helper<int> h;
        h.print(tb);

        return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ pico main.cpp
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
5 p
```

---

However, if you add another class (not a nested one, just another class), it won't have access (of course!) to the private members of `TestBuilder`, see for yourself:

```
class alienClass
{
public:
  /*
   That won't work, you will get:
   error: 'n' is a private member of 'TestBuilder<int, int>'
   error: 'c' is a private member of 'TestBuilder<int, int>'
  */
  void print(TestBuilder<int, int>& tb) {
    std::cout << tb.n << " " << tb.c << std::endl;
  }
};
```